# Let $ T:L^p[0,1]\to :L^p[0,1]$ such that $T(f(x))=x^kf(x)$. Find $||T||$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $ T:L^p[0,1]\to \mathbb :L^p[0,1]$ such that $T(f(x))=x^kf(x)$. Find $||T||$.

My attempt:-

I could successfully prove $||T(f(x))||_p^p\leq \int_0^1 |x^k|^p|f(x)|^pdx\leq \int_0^1 |f(x)|^pdx=||f||_p^p\implies ||T||\leq 1.$ I am not not able to find exact $||T||$. Is there any general technique? I tried to find a function $f$ in the surface of unit ball in $L^p[0,1]$ such that $$||T(f) ||_p=||f||_p$. Could you help me? Is there any general technique?

Comment: Are you sure that $T$ maps onto $\mathbb{R}$? To me it looks like it maps onto $L^p$.

Comment: How is $T$ from $L^{p}\to \Bbb{R}$? . It is taking a function and giving you another function

Comment: An idea is to find the sequence of the functions which norm is tending to $1$ in your case.

Comment: soryy ot is not $\mathbb R$ it is $L_P[0,1]$

Answer (score 3):

$\|T\|=1$ if you treat $T$ as a map from $L^{p}$ into itself. Hint: Let $f_n=n^{1/p}\chi_{(1-\frac 1 n , 1)}$. Then $\|f_n\|_p=1$ and $\int |Tf_n(x)|^{p}dx \to 1$.

Comment: Is there any general technique to find such a sequence? How would you take this very quickly?